# Numpy turning ints to decimals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
myDict = ({"Row 1": [10, np.nan],
           "Row 2": [10, "NaN"]})
myDf = pd.DataFrame(myDict)
```

This results in the following dataframe

[image]

Why does the use of np.nan turn the int to a decimal in the first column?

Comment: `NaN` is a float value, and for performance, pandas will coerce the rest of the series to `float`.  If you mixed dtypes in a row it would be of type `object`, which is not efficient at all.  You should see this when you do `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas is dependent on Numpy for many things.  Among those things is the null value `np.nan`.  Numpy defines that value as `dtype` `np.float`.  Pandas intends to store dataframe columns as single dimensional Numpy arrays.  Numpy requires that all values be cast as the same `dtype`.

This would be fixed if Numpy had a null value for integers but it doesn't... yet.

When Pandas reads the dictionary and realizes that all values are numeric, it has two choices.

1. Cast the entire column as `dtype` `object` and retain the values `[10, np.nan]`
2. Cast the entire column as `dtype` `float` and augment the integer `[10.0, np.nan]`

Pandas chooses the second option because almost always people will be doing numeric calculations and and having `float` is optimized for such things while `object` is not.

On the other column, `[10, "Nan"]` has a string thing in there and Pandas doesn't attempt to make those into `float` and leaves them as `object`.  It'll be up to you to fix it.

Comment: If given `[10, "NaN"]` `numpy would choose a string dtype.  Apparently, `pandas` chooses the `object` route instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDict = ({"Row 1": [10.0, np.nan],
       "Row 2": [10.0, "NaN"]})
```

This should do the trick. If not you can change pandas dataframe value

```
myDf.apply(pd.to_numeric(errors="coerce"))
```

Coerce allows you to ignore nan values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
myDict = ({"Row 1": [10, np.nan],
       "Row 2": [10, "NaN"]})
myDf = pd.to_numeric(myDict, errors="coerce")
```

Comment: The previous answer (by Antonios Katopodis) results in the following error: TypeError: to_numeric() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Answer (score 0):

My guess, is that because you used the quotations in the second column, its treating the NaN as a string. As such, it assigned the Column 2 data type as an "object" instead of an integer or a float. Also np.nan is treated as a float number, so Column 1, which includes both integers and floats, got assigned the more detailed float type.

Using your code above, i ran the following code:

```
In[1]:
type(np.nan)
Out[1]:
float

In[2]:
type("NaN")
Out[2]:
str


In[3]:
myDf.info()

Out[3]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Row 1    1 non-null float64
Row 2    2 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes
```